# I Can't display the Results of a JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql

(Using mysql in php)

Hi people i cant seem to find the answer through google or on this site so help is much appreciated. I'm trying to join 2 tables together displaying JUST the name of students, then to order it alphabetically which i havent gotten into yet help on how to do that is also appreciated :D. 
All info needed is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq1Ew.png)

the id is set to `INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and is the `PRIMARY KEY`
the StudentID is set to `INT`
the Name is set to `VARCHAR(30)`
and the age is set to an `INT` as well.

My question is, why is the following php script not displaying any results? besides the table? I am using wamp.

Comment: You should include the listings in your question and not in a linked image, it's much harder to check things with images.  Also the mysql_ functions are deprecated and you should be looking into either PDO or use the mysqli_ functions.

Comment: You might need a union rather than a join

Comment: Oh ok sorry nigel im new to this site. i'll do that in the future. Thanks for your help as well! but im only a student and the mysql_functions is what we're using in My Certificate at the moment.

Comment: thanks for everyones help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `UNION` both the results and apply `ORDER` on it, e.g.:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM(
    SELECT Name 
    FROM Group1

    UNION 

    SELECT Name
    FROM Group 2
) a
ORDER BY a.Name;
```

Comment: OMG THANKYOU! it worked exactly the way i wanted you're an angel mate !